# Execute code and decide which viewController should be displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app basically reads in a contained `.json` and (depending on the content) displays one of three views. How can this be done in code?

I'm thinking about reading in the file in the `AppDelegate`, but where and how should I create the first vc and display it? Some example code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: actually you dont have to do it in `AppDelegate`, you can use a blank `ViewController` in the begining to perform this operation of reading .json file and determining which view to be displayed and can navigate to the corresponding `ViewController` . If you can't understand it, comment me and I'll do some code and post for you

Answer (score 0):

so this is not about delegate, u can use something like extension for view 
and separated by if or switch

`if mydata == something["mystaff"] as! [String:String] {
use extension view1 here
}
if mydata == somethingElse["anotherStaff"] as! [String:[any]] {
use extension view2 here
}
if mydata == somethingElse2["anotherStaff2"] as! [String:any] {
use extension view2 here
}`

this work for you :)